# found 1 critical severity vulnerability run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

Tags: html, node.js, database, amazon-web-services, npm

I wanted to install mysql. I used 'npm install mysql' I got this eror:
found 1 critical severity vulnerability
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

then I tried 'npm audit fix'
I got this :
npm WARN dell@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN dell@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 0.847s
fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 137 scanned packages
1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do I eliminate this error? I tried to search for this but I didn't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

run: npm audit
it will show you which package needs your attention.

look at this link:
https://go.npm.me/audit-guide

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31081703)